# "one to many" or "many to many" ORMLite implementation

Tags: android, database-design, relational-database, ormlite

I have class contact, which can have a lot of groups and one group can have a lot of contacts.

What model of relationship in ORMLite should I choose?

I looked at [this](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/tree/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/examples/manytomany) official documentation, but I need to have List of groups in the Contact item, so as List of contacts in the Group item.

I understand that it is nooby question, but hope somebody helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a group can contain MANY contacts and a contact can be in MANY groups, then you have a "MANY to MANY" relationship.

Thinking about the relationship in that structure will always tell you what type of relationship to use

1. "A group can contain ONLY ONE contact and a contact can ONLY be part of ONE group" = One to One"
2. A  group can contain ONLY ONE contact and a contact can be part of MANY groups" = "One to Many"
3. "A group can contain MANY contacts and a contact can ONLY be part of ONE group" = One to Many"
4. "A group can contain MANY contacts and a contact can be in MANY groups" = Many to Many